# .Net 6.0 AmbiguousMatchException matched itself?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, .net-6.0

I click on the Create action on a controller and get this. The endpoints match exactly:

```
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: FleetLogix.Intranet.Areas.ReportGroups.Controllers.UnitsController.Create (FleetLogix.Intranet) FleetLogix.Intranet.Areas.ReportGroups.Controllers.UnitsController.Create (FleetLogix.Intranet)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[] candidateState)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ProcessFinalCandidates(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateState[] candidateState)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.Select(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateState[] candidateState)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

My end points are set up as the following in Startup.Configure()  Lots of areas.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "AdminArea",
        areaName: "Admin",
        pattern: "Admin/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "AnchorArea",
        areaName: "Anchor",
        pattern: "Anchor/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "DashboardArea",
        areaName: "Dashboard",
        pattern: "Dashboard/{controller=DriverBehaviour}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "MapsArea",
        areaName: "Maps",
        pattern: "Maps/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "ReportGroupsArea",
        areaName: "ReportGroups",
        pattern: "ReportGroups/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "MaintenanceArea",
        areaName: "Maintenance",
        pattern: "Maintenance/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "TcaArea",
        areaName: "TCA",
        pattern: "TCA/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "ThirdPartySimsArea",
        areaName: "ThirdPartySims",
        pattern: "ThirdPartySims/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllers();

    endpoints.MapRazorPages();


    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Because my post is mostly from config, I need to add some words.  This error hasn't just appeared, and I can't think of a matching change to cause it it.  The endpoints have been pretty static.  What has caused this error?

Please ask for additional logs or config if required.

Comment: In your example you specify the default route twice

Comment: @AluanHaddad sorry, accidental double paste.  fixed!

Comment: Hi @Hecatonchires, please check `FleetLogix.Intranet.Areas.ReportGroups.Controllers.UnitsController`, if it contains two same action (`Create (FleetLogix.Intranet)`).